# Como atribuir um looping ao código - PHP

Tags: php

Preciso que meu código 'recarregue' a cada 5 min. Como?!

**Meu código ele:** *Abre um dashboard, dentro dele tem 2 includes. Um para acessar um site e fazer o download de 3 arquivos CSV e outro que acessa esses arquivos CSV, pega os valores, multiplica e printa o valor na tela.*

Preciso que ele repita esse mesmo processo a cada 5min, ou seja, que fique em looping.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso seria equivalente a dar um refresh na página a cada 5 minutos?

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, acho que sim. Por que isso iria fazer o código ser executado novamente. E com isso, repetir todo o processo. Sim, é viável.

Comment: o método setInterval do javascript resolve seu problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa de PHP, na realidade. Você pode adicionar esse código no seu cabeçalho, que irá forçar a página a recarregar a cada 300 segundos (5 minutos):

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" />
```

Comment: Agradeço! O botão foi besteira, é porque eu tenho esse dashboard em VBA no EXCEL, e lá eu tenho um botão porque o código trava o excel todo e só para quando aperto o botão, vou editar e apagar esse botão. Obrigado :D

Comment: Feliz por ajudar. A resposta também foi editada.